# How this covariance come?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, \cdots ,X_n$ be a random sample from a $N (\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution, and let $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ denote sample mean and sample variance. We know that $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent.

In George Casella's *Statistical Inference*, page 222, he rewrote
$$\bar{X}=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{1}{n})X_i,$$
$$X_j-\bar{X}=\sum_{i=1}^n(\delta_{ij}-\frac{1}{n})X_i,$$
where $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ otherwise. Then my question is, why
$$\textrm{Cov}(\bar{X},X_j-\bar{X})=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{1}{n})(\delta_{ij}-\frac{1}{n}).$$
Of course the right hand side equals to $0$, but I don't know why the covariance equal to right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have mentioned that he's applying a lemma – how did you think we'd be able to guess that without the book?

[Here's a copy of the book](https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf). This calculation is intended “as an illustration of the application of Lemma $5.3.3$”. Upon comparison with item a. in Lemma $5.3.3$ (p. $220$), it seems that it's a typo and he forgot the factor $\sigma^2$.

Comment: I am sorry I did not notice he used a lemma to prove so. No wondering he said "easy" to show.